# Redirect users to web server based on user IP

Tags: webserver, iis, windows

I have a web server that has windows authentication, I want to disable the windows authentication locally, anyone on the local network can access it without authentication. after long research I have not found any way. But, I believe that I can create two web servers that uses the same domain name, one used locally and one with public ip address. but the issue how I will redirect the local users to the local webserver ?

Comment: I'd be surprised if IIS wasn't able to be configured for local access without a password.  Apache can do that really easily.

Comment: I'm not clear what the question is.   IIS with Windows authentication shouldn't ask for a password when the IIS server is in the same domain with as the users Active Directory users.  It should only prompt for user when user and IIS Directory Servers are different assuming your NTFS permissions are correct.

Comment: @Trebor, SSO requires additional server-side and client side configuration. There are many SharePoint related docs regarding this. Based on content provided by OP, that type of SSO is out of scope.